# Why doesn't an entry appear in my timeline when my friend tagged me in his post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

He wrote a long article and tagged a lot of people, some of whom are not my friends. It is a public post.

I opened the page of someone that is tagged in the same post and I could see the entry for it in his timeline, but in my own timeline, I can't see it.

Also, I can't see those who were tagged in the same post on my friend's timeline.

Comment: Do you have Facebook set to require your approval for tags? If so, it will be in your *Timeline Review* section.

Comment: no disabled. never enabled.

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Activity page.

```
http://www.facebook.com/your-username-here/allactivity
```

You can see the mentioned post there.

Next to that you can see options on right side.

Check whether that post is hidden from your timeline. If so, change it to "Allowed on timeline".

Hope this helps. :)

[image: Facebook allactivity]

Comment: I can not see that post in activity log. And it is not photo.

Comment: He gave you an example, not you real post.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your timeline and click on *View Activity log*.

Then look at the left-top corner, there you will find *Tag review* and *Timeline review*. Click on one of them (actually which is required to click- if someone tagged you then you need to click on tag review. So is Timeline review if anyone tag you in any post").

Then you can see post(s) or picture(s),if any, where you are tagged. Then look at the top-right of that post and you will find option to *Hide from timeline* or *Allow on your timeline*.